# image is not being displayed in UIImageView even though it is being set

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a collectionViewHeader with a UIImageView, set to have a grey backgroundColor. There's an addPhotoButton and it takes the user to another Controller. When they select the image, it returns to the original controller and it's supposed to be the image in the UIImageView.

Here's the code from the collectionViewHeader:

```
var selectedImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        self.imageView.image = selectedImage!
        print("This is the selectedImage:", selectedImage!)
    }
}


let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 234, green: 246, blue: 246)
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    return iv
}()
```

This is what every tutorial or StackOverflow post I came across said to do. And the print statement:

```
print("This is the selectedImage:", selectedImage!)
```

is printing out:

```
This is the selectedImage: <UIImage: 0x600001000380>, {485, 482}
```

So the image is there, but it's not being put in the UIImageView.

The imageView is being added to the subview and anchored to set the size in the header's init:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(imageView)
    addSubview(addimageButton)
    addSubview(addimageText)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
        eventImageView.anchor(top: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: frame.width, height: 175)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier OS?
    }
    addimageButton.anchor(top: eventImageView.topAnchor, left: eventImageView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: imageView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 25, paddingLeft: (imageView.bounds.size.width - addimageButton.bounds.size.width) / 2, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    addimageText.anchor(top: nil, left: imageView.leftAnchor, bottom: imageView.bottomAnchor, right: imageView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: (imageView.bounds.size.width - addimageButton.bounds.size.width) / 2, paddingBottom: 25, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

The `selectedImage` is being set in the header of the other Controller here:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! PhotoSelectorHeader

    self.header = header

    header.photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    if let selectedImage = selectedImage {
        if let index = self.images.index(of: selectedImage) {
            let selectedAsset = self.assets[index]

            let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
            imageManager.requestImage(for: selectedAsset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .default, options: nil, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

                header.photoImageView.image = image

            })

        }
    }

    return header
}

fileprivate func setupNavigationButtons() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNext))
}

@objc func handleNext() {
    let addPhotoHeader = AddPhotoHeader()
    addPhotoHeader.selectedImage = header?.photoImageView.image
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

I'm sure there's a quick step I'm missing here, but I've been stuck for a couple days now!

If you think the problem might be somewhere else in my project, let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Where are you setting the image?

Comment: You need to send imageview to root viewcontroller with using protocol

Comment: @Bot I just edited the post to show where I set the image. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Where do you set the frame or size of the photoImageView?

Comment: And where do you add it as subview for that matter?

Comment: Can you please post some images or preferably a video showing your use case. It will help in better understanding of your problem

Comment: @florieger I added it in the subview of the header and anchored it for the size. Posted that in the original question for ya!

Comment: You set the image view's background color to gray... Are you seeing the gray rectangle *before* you tap the addPhoto button?

Comment: @DonMag yeah I’m seeing the gray rectangle, which is why I’m confident the problem has to do with the image being set

Comment: The issue is you are setting the image in a background thread when it needs to be set on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You aren't calling this on the main thread (which *could* work if it's being set from the main thread, but I'll assume it isn't since the UIImageView isn't updating appropriately.
2. (Optional to fix) You're asking for a crash by force casting that optional `selectedImage`.

```
var selectedImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // Don't force-cast (!) the optional selectedImage.
            // Since you can assign a nil image to self?.imageView.image, do that instead
            // Other option is adding a guard-statement here:
            // guard selectedImage != nil else { return }
            self?.imageView.image = selectedImage
            print("This is the selectedImage:", selectedImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever something UI-related is being set but not visually updating, and everything else seems fine, there's a good chance that jumping to the main-thread will work. The main-thread is reserved for all user interface changes, such as updating an image, refreshing a table view, or messing with constraints.

Pretty much any object that has `UI` in it (`UIImageView`) needs to be updated on the main thread only. Issues that can arise can range from a major delay in the UI-object updating to crashes.

However, any long running tasks or heavy processes, such as network requests or working with pictures at a pixel-level, should **not** be run on the main thread, otherwise your user interface **will** come to a halt while that process finishes.

@twostraws (Twitter) does a great job explaining the main thread here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/9/4/back-to-the-main-thread-dispatchqueuemain

He mentions this and I can't agree more:

> That's so important it bears repeating twice: **it's never OK to do user interface work on the background thread.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need `[weak self]`

Comment: I choose to avoid holding strong references to self whenever possible, it's up to the dev if they want to include it or not

Comment: Okay, this makes alot of sense since I was fetching the photos with `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`. However, now the image is printing out as `nil`. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Does it print `nil` twice, by chance? Pushing to another thread can take a very short amount of time, literally milli/nanoseconds, but that can be long enough if you accidentally set it a second time as `nil`.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that you did set it twice. There's always the possibility of a race conflict where you are setting it with `nil` and then setting it with the image, but it sets them in the reverse order. The issue is that it happens so fast for our eyes to notice. Other than this issue, I don't believe moving something to the main thread could do this. Did you make any other changes? (Also you are holding a strong reference in `imageManager` to the header. Since it is a closure, it will likely be run after you return header. This could be part of your issue–look at the first two comments.)

Comment: Where am i setting it twice? (By the way, it's only printing out nil once) I'm confused as to where it could be nil. In the controller where `selectedImage` is coming from, there is always an image picked (kind of like in Instagram when you go to add a photo to post). Also, when I took away `[weak self]` as @Bot suggested, it printed out `This is the selectedImage: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600001c5fa30>, {485, 482})`

Comment: @AlecO should I add the portion where I fetch the photos on the `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` to the post? Would that make it easier to see the problem?